# How to enable/disable a button when Datatables has checkbox selected row

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables

How can I enable/disable my button when there is a selected checkbox row in my datatable?

```
var pctoreceive = $('#pcToReceive').DataTable({
           'columnDefs': [{
                'targets': 0,
                'searchable': false,
                'orderable': false,
                'className': 'dt-body-center',
                'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="'
                       + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
                }
            }],
```

I've shorten my code. Above shows that I added a new column for `checkbox` select

[image]

Those two button must be disabled when there is no selected row. Otherwise enable

```
$('#rc-select-all').on('click', function() {
    // Check/uncheck all checkboxes in the table
    var rows = pctoreceive.rows({
        'search': 'applied'
    }).nodes();
    $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', this.checked);
});

// Handle click on checkbox to set state of "Select all" control
$('#pcToReceive tbody').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    // If checkbox is not checked
    if (!this.checked) {
        var el = $('#rc-select-all').get(0);
        // If "Select all" control is checked and has 'indeterminate' property
        if (el && el.checked && ('indeterminate' in el)) {
            // Set visual state of "Select all" control 
            // as 'indeterminate'
            el.indeterminate = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with datatable.

Just set a counter variable to store how much input check are checked, then if > 0 enable your button.

See this small example (and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zL36j5gu/))

```
var counterChecked = 0;

$('body').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {

    this.checked ? counterChecked++ : counterChecked--;
    counterChecked > 0 ? $('#submitButton').prop("disabled", false): $('#submitButton').prop("disabled", true);

});
```

Comment: why is it on body? why not on the specific table?

Comment: just because i didn't put any table on my example, but in your code you should use the specific table selector ofc :)

Comment: i tried it and it only works on the rows.. but not in the select/deselect checkbox on the header

Comment: because you're catching events only in the tbody `$('#pcToReceive tbody')`.. change it in `$('#pcToReceive')`

Comment: also.. ..by default there no selected row.. how can I disabled the button?
although I have a condition where could i disabled the button when the table is empty but i don't know how to add in condition when the table has no selected on load..

Comment: if it's disabled by default add the property `disabled` in the HTML, so it will render already disabled. like in my above example: `<input id="submitButton" type="submit" disabled value="Submit">`

Comment: i already did that.. but because of my condition `if (!pctoreceive.data().count()) {
                $('button[value="Receive"]').prop('disabled', false);
                $('button[value="Cancel"]').prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else {
                $('button[value="Receive"]').prop('disabled', true);
                $('button[value="Cancel"]').prop('disabled', true);
            }`
it will be enabled because it is not empty.. though I had to disable it because it has no selected on pageload

Comment: so this code shuold be removed. Button's Enable/Disabled should be managed only by checked input, not by this condition `if (!pctoreceive.data().count())`

Comment: then how would i handle to disable the button when the datatable is empty?

Comment: it would be already disabled, by default, if you put attribute `disabled` in your HTML code

Comment: oh I get it now.. I'm so dumb.. haha.. .so whether empty or not, it would be disabled since it has an attribute `disabled` in HTML code. Thank you for helping.